# MOSFET as a switch: operation region during Rise time

Tags: powermosfet

In the below picture, during the time period Tri the drain current Id starts increasing linearly wrt gate voltage Vgs and the voltage Vds is clamped to Vd since the drain current hasn't yet taken up all the load current. So during this period since Vds>(Vgs-Vth), is the MOSFET operating in saturation region. Does MOSFET has to operate in saturation region for a small time period(Tri) even when the MOSFET acts as a switch.
If the MOSFET operates in Saturation region for this small duration(Tri), then does the current should increase parabolically since in saturation region Id=K(Vgs-Vth)^2 ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: TL;DR the reason you use gate drivers is to quickly charge/discharge the gate capacitance and get through the region where the FET is *partially* on as quickly as possible.

Comment: Note how above comment also applies to your next question!